# .NET always installed and enabled on Windows 10?

Tags: .net, windows, frameworks, system-requirements

So far, our windows application based on MFC does not have any framework requirements. It runs as portable app on hundreds of Windows PCs. Our customers love it!

We'd wish to use C# .NET in our future version where we drop Windows 7 support.

So, can we run our application on any Windows 8+ system? (majority will be Windows 10)

I am aware of https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies, but can the administrator still uninstall or initially not install .NET?

Our customers operate large quantities of Windows PCs and run the bare windows system on them that came with the computer. It was always impossible to use .NET under Windows 7 and below, because on some computers .NET wasn't installed or disabled and our customers were not happy to change that.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to uninstall .Net. But your MFC app wasn't as universal as you realize, either. It relied on an MFC runtime that was also possible to uninstall. As a practical matter, .Net is just as available, if you're careful about choosing the correct runtime. See here for versions, and remember that once .Net is installed, Windows Update will help keep it current https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/

Comment: Is it installed and enabled by default?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn After reading https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/ I learnt we have to make the distinction between "Installed as part of the OS" and "can be added or removed via the Programs and Features control panel". Unfortunatly I am not sure if "part of the OS" means it can't be disabled. Where would be the place to disable it, if it's part of the OS?

Comment: It cannot be disabled. The framework us either installed or not.

Comment: Can it still be uninstalled if it is an OS component? E.g. _Windows 7 (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 3.5.1 as an OS component_ **or** _Windows 10 April 2018 Update (all editions) includes the .NET Framework 4.7.2 as an OS component, and it is installed by default._ according to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/

Comment: Yes, but that is not the same as disabled. The confusion may be the check marks for the Add/Remove Windows Features dialog. Those cause a feature to be installed/uninstalled rather than enabled/disabled. And it is possible to uninstall .Net from Windows 8/10, just like you can for MFC... but not through that control panel item. That only controls the old 2.0/3.5 version of the entire.

Comment: s/entire/runtime. Silly auto-correct

Comment: I'm afraid .Net can't be uninstalled from Windows 10. That's what they always say, when people ask to uninstall .Net from Windows 10. https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&q=uninstall+dotnet+windows+10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [microsoft technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/94af5867-5641-4a45-a3c4-9c04b02ada56/how-to-remove-net-framework-47-from-windows-10?forum=win10itprosetup) .NET 4.x can't neither be uninstalled nor disabled on Windows 10.

**More quotes:**

> "Windows 10 systems, however, with current updates from Microsoft,
>   will not have any option to uninstall .NET. However, if your overall
>   Windows Updates are not current, it may be possible to install the
>   latest .NET version."

Source: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-remove-and-reinstall-the-Microsoft-NET-Framework.html

> The .NET Framework 3.5 is an optional component that can be disabled
>   via the Windows Features control panel. The .NET Framework 4.x is not
>   optional though, and it cannot be disabled when it is installed as a
>   part of Windows.

Source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/#comment-234605